# MYSQL partial match.... bit what you think

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in MYSQL to do a partial match but the opposite way round to how this is normally done..

I.E I have a website for checking.... voucher codes

A user types "WUD092050549E" and hits search

I want the database to return... any row with column_x matching

- "WUD092050549E" - exact match
- "WUD0920" - 7 character match
- "WUD0" - 4 character match

**BUT NOT**

- "WUD039540" - 4 character match, then incorrect
- "123213WUD092050549E2334" - incorrect characters, then match

Essentially where the row matches 4 or more characters (in the same sequence) with no mistakes

I know exact matches can be achieved by.. "SELECT * WHERE column_x="WUD092050549E"

For myself I ideally want to sort exact matches, then if none were found other less accurate matches (so two queries possibly)

Comment: Are you using a Server_Side Language to do the Query?  If so it would be much easier to manipulate the data by doing a SELECT *  ..  Put it in an array, and then use something like this in PHP `$var = substr('WUD039540', 0, 4);`  ..   That would return what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
SELECT 1 from DUAL 
WHERE column_x LIKE 'WUD092050549E%'
or INSTR('WUD092050549E', column_x ) > 0
```

You can check it out [**HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1691)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the original post but I think instr = 1 should work... then making minimum search length 4 or more

Comment: not `=1` but `>0` cause it could have any positive value, check [**this**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1691) out (see that the last query is from the *NOT* section and it returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the specification is.

If you want to check for an entire match, the first seven characters, or the first four characters:

```
SELECT t.voucher_code='WUD092050549E' AS exact_match
     , t.*
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.voucher_code = 'WUD092050549E'
    OR t.voucher_code = LEFT('WUD092050549E',7)
    OR t.voucher_code = LEFT('WUD092050549E',4)
```

If you want any length voucher code to match, you could enumerate all possibilities:

```
SELECT t.voucher_code = 'WUD092050549E' AS exact_match
     , t.*
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.voucher_code = 'WUD092050549E'
    OR t.voucher_code = LEFT('WUD092050549E',11)
    OR t.voucher_code = LEFT('WUD092050549E',10)
    OR t.voucher_code = LEFT('WUD092050549E',9)
    OR t.voucher_code = LEFT('WUD092050549E',8)
    OR t.voucher_code = LEFT('WUD092050549E',7)
    OR t.voucher_code = LEFT('WUD092050549E',6)
    OR t.voucher_code = LEFT('WUD092050549E',5)
    OR t.voucher_code = LEFT('WUD092050549E',4)
```

Slower, but more concise:

```
SELECT t.voucher_code
     , t.*
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.voucher_code = LEFT('WUD092050549E',CHAR_LENGTH(t.voucher_code))
```

But I'm not sure I understand the specification, so this may be way off from what you are looking for.